# Can I access an EditText variable from first one to second one

Tags: android

I have two Java files
The first one `extends` `AppCompactActivity`
And the second one `extends` `SQLiteDataBaseHelper`

So this is the question:

Can I access an `EditText` variable from first one to second one?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a consulting/design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We however can can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can and Edit Text at the end is a place to store data so you can create an instant of that class you want to access and then you can use setters to set data or getters to get it, check this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText ; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public EditText getEditText(){
    return editText ; 
}

public void setEditText(EditText editText){
    this.editText = editText;
}
```

here is the database class :

```
public class access extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private MainActivity mainActivity= new MainActivity() ;

public void setData(EditText editText){
mainActivity.setEditText(editText);
}
```

Comment: Thank for giving answer